# Run AppleScript progress bar in separate window from command line?

Tags: applescript

To display dialogs from the command line I just use

```
$ osascript File.scpt
```

However, the progress bar feature isn't constrained to a dialog window because it adapts to the current application, e.g. a Finder window, where the progress updates are shown on the bottom of the window. File.scpt would look something like this.

```
set numUpdates to 100
set progress total steps to numUpdates
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Updating..."
set progress additional description to "Preparing to process."
set cycle to 1

repeat with a from 1 to numUpdates
    # update description, completed steps, etc
end repeat
```

When I run my script from a terminal window, however, the script runs but nothing is shown to indicate the progress. Is there a way to force the progress bar to open as a new dialog or something along those lines without having to export the script as a ".app" file?

Comment: No. theres no osx provided window like a dialog with a progress bar. for this you need to create an application or output the progress as text the termibal

Answer (score 0):

The reason Script Editor can display progress in its window and Terminal cannot is because Script Editor has its own extended scripting definition with the extra functions so when the script is run via script editor it has been programmed with the extra progress indicator but no other applications are sorry. The way I see it, you pretty much have 2 ways I can think of that will let you display "Progress" in AppleScript:

1. This is kinda ugly but I used to just have a transparent spinner gif file that will be displayed in a dialog which will give the affect that something is loading or working. and a single button saying Nothing or OK eg.

   ```
   display dialog "Loading..." buttons:{"OK"} with icon ("/path/to/loader.gif" as POSIX file)
   ```

   And if you wanna make it temporary just add `giving up after (duration in seconds)`
2. This is probably the best option but it is probably more complicated. I advise that you transfer to a programming language called "AppleScript Objective C" otherwise known as "Cocoa AppleScript". This allows you to use the basic AppleScript commands with Cocoa Windows/Dialogs/etc including progress bars!. to start you off you should download Xcode and research AppleScript Objective C and perhaps stick to it. Its better than AppleScript but still has the same functions :)

Comment: So there is no way to bind the progress bar to a dialog? That's unfortunate. Thank you for your suggestions, but I picked AppleScript specifically for the reason of not having to get other files involved within my bash script.